# Removing trailing white space after \ref and \autoref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, ref, autoref

I've used \autoref and \ref throughout my whole document and I have a trailing space through on each reference to figures (see photo).

From what I can tell I may need to protect the end of lines, but I'm not sure how I can do that. Do I need to redefine \autoref and \ref? how would I do this as I'm a bit new to latex.

here is the code `(\autoref{fig:fig:H2P-homology-indices},\ref{fig:fig:P2H-homology-indices}).`

which gives the following output
[image: extra spaces after each ref]

I'd like to make it  (Figure III.3.8, III.3.7).43

Comment: you should show a small but complete example, that makes it much easier to test your issue. By default autoref doesn't intersuch a space, so something in your code is doing it.

Comment: Thanks. I added a trailing space when I redefined \thefigure. oops.